# Getting cannot load file in Rails 7.0.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Updated to 7.0.7.1 and now am getting "cannot find file" errors when requiring rails when running a Rake task. This happens when I try to run a rake task or even "rake --task".

Have tried changing zeitwerk autoload_paths and fiddling with different zeitwerk config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the file permissions were changed on 7.0.7.1 incorrectly.

Updating to 7.0.7.2 fixed the problem.

[Rails Release 7.0.7.2](https://rubyonrails.org/2023/8/22/Rails-Versions-7-0-7-2-6-1-7-6-have-been-released)